# How to fill authomaticallyNAs based on values from nearest year (R)

Tags: r, time-series

All

I would like to ask if I can make the data frame look like the picture I have uploaded (R program).

I am trying to fill in NA values from the closest years. I would like to use mean value if the given year is exactly between past or coming years with values (in 2012 in the picture). And I want to fill the rest of years without values with the values from values in the nearest year. For example, data in 2010, 2011 from 2009 and in 2013, and 2014 from 2015.

[image]

I would really appreciate it if you can give me any ideas on how to make it. I used this code:

```
mutate(Essonne = case_when(is.na(Essonne) & !is.na(lag(Essonne)) & is.na(lead(Essonne)) ~ lag(Essonne), is.na(Essonne) & is.na(lag(Essonne)) & !is.na(lead(Essonne)) ~ lead(Essonne), TRUE ~ Essonne) %>% na.approx(.))
```

(Essonne is the same as "Before" in the picture) but it has made all the years everything with mean between last and next year.....)

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this could be to use kNN-imputation, which is for instance in the VIM package.

```
     # the data frame
     tibble(year = c(2008:2016),
     before = c(2.5,2.5, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 0.03,0.03)) %>% 

     ## the imputation
     VIM::kNN(k = 2)


     #output 
     year before year_imp before_imp
     1 2008  2.500    FALSE      FALSE
     2 2009  2.500    FALSE      FALSE
     3 2010  2.500    FALSE       TRUE
     4 2011  2.500    FALSE       TRUE
     5 2012  1.265    FALSE       TRUE
     6 2013  0.030    FALSE       TRUE
     7 2014  0.030    FALSE       TRUE
     8 2015  0.030    FALSE      FALSE
     9 2016  0.030    FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! It was very helpful. May I ask you something more? I tried to find an answer but could you explain the meaning of k in this case?  Since I have a dataset from 2000 to 2020 and  in 2000 and 2020 have the values in the worst case. I am confused what k number i have to use.